# Find all directories, that don't contain other directories

Tags: bash, find

Currently:

```
$ find -type d
./a
./a/sub
./b
./b/sub
./b/sub/dub
./c/sub
./c/bub
```

I need:

```
$ find -type d -not -contains -type d
./a/sub
./b/sub/dub
./c/sub
./c/bub
```

How do I exclude directories, that contain other (sub)directories, but are not empty (contain files)?

Comment: You basically want to do a `find -type d`, but areonly interested in the Leaf nodes of the tree. Here one idea for an approach: Do a `find -type d|sort` and pipe the result into a loop. Whenever you have two successive lines X and Y, and the length of line Y is not larger than the length of line X, the line X must be a directory you are interested in.

Comment: You are interested in : `find -type d -links 2 ! -empty`. (See [(U&L) How to find only directories without subdirectories?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/497185/273492) Remark that this might fail on some filesystems such as BTRFS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `find` the leaf directories that only have 2 links (or less) and then check if each found directory contains some files.

Something like this:

```
# find leaf directories
find -type d -links -3 -print0 | while read -d '' dir
do
    # check if it contains some files
    if ls -1qA "$dir" | grep -q .
    then
        echo "$dir"
    fi
done
```

Or simply:

```
find -type d -links -3 ! -empty
```

Note that you may need the `find` option `-noleaf` on some filesystems, like CD-ROM or some MS-DOS filesystems. It works without it in WSL2 though.

In the [btrfs](/questions/tagged/btrfs) filesystem the directories always have 1 link so using `-links` won't work there.

A much slower, but filesystem agnostic, `find` based version:

```
prev='///' # some impossible dir

# A depth first find to collect non-empty directories
readarray -d '' dirs < <(find -depth -type d ! -empty -print0)

for dir in "${dirs[@]}"
do
    dirterm=$dir'/'

    # skip if it matches the previous dir
    [[ $dirterm == ${prev:0:${#dirterm}} ]] && continue

    # skip if it has sub directories
    [[ $(find "$dir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print -quit) != '' ]] && continue

    echo "$dir"
    prev=$dir
done # add "| sort" if you want the same order as a "find" without "-depth"
```

Comment: It seems this cannot be use in WSL, as all directories have `links == 1`

Comment: @Philippe That may be a limitation in WSL1. It works in WSL2.

Comment: This doesn't work on `btrfs` because link count for a directory in `btrfs` is different than that of the classical Unix file systems.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin How many links does an empty `btrfs` directory show if one uses the `-noleaf` option? Less than 2? If so, that may be fixed with my latest edit.

Comment: It appears it is always 1 for directories (leaf or non-leaf). It is discussed [here](https://linux-btrfs.vger.kernel.narkive.com/oAoDX89D/btrfs-st-nlink-for-directories)

Comment: @M.NejatAydin I see. I guess one has to do something even more involved on those then. I may add that when I come home in a few hours if OP wants that too.

Comment: This still reports directories that have multiple subdirectories but no files on my Windows git-bash emulation.

Comment: @PaulHodges Even with `-noleaf`?

Comment: Yep. Might just be a bug in this version.

Comment: @PaulHodges True but a truely generic solution should be able to handle all filesystems. I may have to add less effective as a fallback later.

Comment: @PaulHodges I added a find-based filesystem agnostic version. It's not as fast as your bash glob-based one though :-)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't show us which of these directories do and do not contain files. You specify files, so I'm working on the assumption that you only want directories that have no subdirectories but do have files.

```
shopt -s dotglob nullglob globstar     # customize glob evaluation
for d in **/                           # loop directories only
do for s in "${d}"*/                   # check subdirs in each
   do [[ -h "$s" ]] || continue 2      # skip dirs with subdirs
   done
   for f in "${d}"*                    # check for nondirs in each
   do echo "$d"                        # there's something here!
      continue 2                       # done with this dir, check next
   done
done
```

`dotglob` includes "hidden" files whose names start with a "dot" (`.foo`)
`nullglob` makes `no*such` return *nothing* instead of the string 'no*such'.
`globstar` makes `**/` match arbitrary depth - e.g., `./x/`, `./x/y/`, and `./x/y/z/`.

`for d in **/` loops over all subdirectories, including subdirectories of subdirectories, though the trailing `/` means it will only report directories, not files.

`for s in "${d}"*/` loops over all the subdirectories of `$d` if there are any. `nullglob` means if there are none, the loop won't execute at all. If we see a subdirectory, `[[ -h "$s" ]] || continue 2` says if it entered this loop at all, symlinks are ok, but anything else disqualifies `$d`, so skip up 2 enclosing loops and advance the top level to the next dir.

if it gets this far, there are no invalidating real subdirectories, so we have to confirm there *are* files of some sort, even if they are just symlinks to other directories. `for f in "${d}"*` loops through anything else in the directory, since we know there aren't subdirs. It won't even enter the loop if the directory doesn't have *something* because of the `nullglob`, so if it goes in at all, anything there is a reason to report the dir (`echo "$d"`) as non-empty. Once that's done, there's no reason to keep checking, so `continue 2` again advances the top loop to the next dir to check!

I expected `**/` to work, but it fails to get any subdirectories at all on my Windows/Git Bash emulation. `**/*/` ignores subdirectories of the current directory, which is why I originally used `*/ **/*/`, but `**/` prevents redundancies when run on a proper Centos VM. Use that.

Comment: `**/` should expand to directories and subdirectories recursively. I've just tested and it works as intended.

Comment: Agreed - but isn't working on my emulation.  Working as it should on a Centos VM. Likely a WIndows/Git Bash bug.

Comment: The problem with these questions is that OP never clarifies how symlinks to existing directories should be handled. Ted's answer considers such symlinks regular files, while yours see them as directories, and both makes equal sense.

Comment: Paul: I hope I didn't violate your answer by adding `dotglob`. I did that because I noticed that it missed listing directories only containing files/directories starting with `.`. Anyway, this does the job pretty quickly so you got my vote.

Comment: It's a fair call. I tend not to include hidden files in things like this unless they are specifically requested ( they are hidden, after all XD ) , but it's a great way to pick them up, the discussion about it adds value, and it's an easy feature to turn on/off with a `#`.

Comment: Symlinks and others should be considered as regular files, as indicated by `-not -contains -type d` (everything except directories). Pardon for not clarifying earlier.

Comment: edited to treat symlinks to directories as file entries, not actual dirs.

Comment: @PaulHodges With the new edit, if the first subdir is a symlink, but there's a second, real, subdir, it'll continue and print that `$d` (if it contains files). Btw, `${sub[0]}` will never be a symlink, will it? It contains a trailing `/` so `-h ${sub[$idx]%/}` might be better. I also think `nullglob` can simplify it somewhat too.

Comment: Was just noticing that. :(  `${sub[0]} ` can be a symlink.  Will have to think about this some more.

Comment: Rechecked my short-circuit logic. Please look it over again?

Comment: Really nice! I found only one discrepancy: I have a test path with spaces `foo/ a  b / c  d / symlink to dir ` that it missed - other than that, it matches `find -type d -links 2 ! -empty` (on an `ext4` filesystem).